# Opencv Kotlin Android /Image template/

Tags: android, kotlin, opencv

please tell me,

1. How do I add the opencv android kotlin library? If you can in detail how and where to throw files along the path to folders and connect, and then only the explorer (root is available) and CodeAssist on the phone
2. How to use opencv android kotlin to use the image template function (search for images on the android screen using a template)?
   at least links

Comment: Why this tag is fun! Android is broaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad.

Answer (score 0):

For

1. In settings.gradle add something like after downloading the [android sdk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.5.5/opencv-4.5.5-android-sdk.zip/download) and installing it.

```
def opencvsdk='C:\\opencv-4.5.5-android-sdk\\OpenCV-android-sdk\\sdk'
include ':opencv'
project(':opencv').projectDir = new File(opencvsdk + '/sdk')
```

Then in your App `build.gradle`

```
implementation project(':opencv')
```

2. There are some samples in the sdk to get you going but not using the template search.

Comment: can I learn more about how I can download opencv manually? where to throw files, hi, I program on the phone

Comment: If you are familiar with programming for Android using Android Studio on a computer, then I'm sure you can download the zip file and unzip it on your development computer. Once you add the details I gave to the build configuration files that Android Studio uses it will build and include opencv in to your App. Where to put them is not relevant as along as the config points to the same place it should work.

Comment: and in which file should I register it? settings.gradle and build.gradle? I want to see how completely the file will look like

Comment: Both as detailed in the answer.

Comment: and how to implement "image template" with this library, or otherwise how: image search on the android screen and action (click, gesture, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To add the OpenCV Library to your Android Studio (Kotlin) project just follow these steps:

- Download the [Android SDK](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/) by clicking on the link, then going in the latest version and selecting the android-sdk file.
- Head over to your Android Studio, open/start a project and load the module downloaded locally by going in **File->New->Import Module**.
- In your `build.grade (app)` file, add the following dependency.

`implementation project(":opencv")`

- In the same file, add

  android {
  packagingOptions {

  ```
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
  ```

  }
  }
- You can use OpenCV now!

Here are some links which may kickstart and help you to get a better idea in implementing your image template

- https://github.com/torcellite/imageComparator
- https://github.com/akshika47/OpenCV-Android-Object-Detection
- https://learnopencv.com/image-classification-with-opencv-for-android/

Comment: can I learn more about how I can download opencv manually? where to throw files, hi, I program on the phone